# Time Series: Whether a proces is invertible or not ?

Tags: statistics, time-series

If the roots of a characteristic polynomial of a MA(2) process are on the unit circle, i.e. z = 1,
is the process still invertible?

Comment: By definition, such a time series is _not_ invertible.

Comment: roots have to be greater than 1 right?